# Nesting conditionals, consolidating functionality in elisp

Tags: org-table, conditionals

Working in an org-mode file, I have this table

```
#+tblname: site-charac-matrix
|   | glaze | orn | color | thin |
|---+-------+-----+-------+------|
| A |     0 |   1 |     0 |    0 |
| B |     1 |   0 |     0 |    0 |
| C |     1 |   0 |     1 |    0 |
| D |     1 |   1 |     1 |    1 |
| E |     0 |   1 |     1 |    1 |
```

which represents archaeological dig sites (one per row) for pottery, where four characteristics of the pottery are noted, 1 or 0 for yes or no for that characteristic of the pottery. Here is the "internal" list for the table

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :var site-matrix=site-charac-matrix :results raw
site-matrix
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
((A 0 1 0 0) (B 1 0 0 0) (C 1 0 1 0) (D 1 1 1 1) (E 0 1 1 1))
```

I created this function to input a site and a characteristic argument and get back a yes or no statement

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :var site-matrix=site-charac-matrix
(defun site-charac-4 (site charac)
  (cond  ((= site 1) (format "At site %d the pottery %s have the %s characteristic." 
                 site (if (= 1 (nth (charac-to-index charac) (nth 0 site-matrix))) "does" "does not") charac)) 
     ((= site 2) (format "At site %d the pottery %s have the %s characteristic."
                 site (if (= 1 (nth (charac-to-index charac) (nth 1 site-matrix))) "does" "does not") charac))
     ((= site 3) (format "At site %d the pottery %s have the %s characteristic."
                 site (if (= 1 (nth (charac-to-index charac) (nth 2 site-matrix))) "does" "does not") charac))
     ((= site 4) (format "At site %d the pottery %s have the %s characteristic."
                 site (if (= 1 (nth (charac-to-index charac) (nth 3 site-matrix))) "does" "does not") charac))
     ((= site 5) (format "At site %d the pottery %s have the %s characteristic."
                 site (if (= 1 (nth (charac-to-index charac) (nth 4 site-matrix))) "does" "does not") charac))
     (t nil)))
#+end_src
```

As you see, I have a `cond` to sort for the incoming site number, but then I need another conditional, an `if` embedded in each `cond` to get the yes or no of the characteristic from the site's row list. In addition, to translate the characteristics, I have this function

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
(defun charac-to-index (charac)
  (pcase charac
    ('glaze 1)
    ('orn 2)
    ('color 3)
    ('thin 4)))
#+end_src
```

which gives `nth` an index for accessing the correct place in the site row lists. This all works

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :var site-matrix=site-charac-matrix
(site-charac-4 5 'color)
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
At site 5 the pottery does have the color characteristic.
```

My Lisp beginner's question is, could some of this be consolidated, e.g., the `charac-to-index`into the main function? Also, how do you have nested conditionals? I can't help but think my use of `if` embedded in the `format` of each `cond` case is kludgy. Any insights appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I think indexing org tables by column and row names is such a general task that it deserves a general function `org+-table-get`.

You could put the following code into your initialization file.

```el
(defsubst org+-table-get-row (table row-id &optional start noerror)
  "Get Org TABLE row by ROW-ID.
Search for ROW-ID from START.
START is zero-based. It defaults to 1.
That way the header row is skipped.
Don't panic in the case of out-of-range access if NOERROR is nil."
  (unless (numberp start)
    (setq start 1))
  (unless (or
       noerror
       (>= start 0)
       (< start (length table)))
    (user-error "Start row index %s out of range [0,%s)" start (length table)))
  (when (< start 0)
    (setq start 0))
  (when (symbolp row-id)
    (setq row-id (symbol-name row-id)))
  (let ((ret (assoc row-id (nthcdr start table))))
    (unless (or noerror ret)
      (user-error "Row %s not found" row-id))
    ret))

(defun org+-table-get (table row-id col-id &optional start-row start-col noerror value)
  "Get Org TABLE element content by ROW-ID and COL-ID.
Search rows from START-ROW and cols from START-COL.
START-ROW and START-COL are zero-based and default to 1.
That way the header row and the column with the row names are skipped.
Don't panic in the case of out-of-range access if NOERROR is nil.
If VALUE is non-nil then assign VALUE to the table cell."
  (when (symbolp col-id)
    (setq col-id (symbol-name col-id)))
  (unless (numberp start-col)
    (setq start-col 1))
  (let* ((col-nr (+ start-col (cl-position col-id (nthcdr start-col (car table)) :test #'equal)))
     (row (if col-nr
          (org+-table-get-row table row-id start-row noerror)
        (unless noerror
          (user-error "Column %s not found" col-id)))))
    (and row
     (if value
         (setf (nth col-nr row) value)
       (nth col-nr row)))))

(defun org+-table-setter (&rest args)
  ""
  (let ((val (car (last args)))
     (n (length args)))
     (setq args (butlast args))
     (when (< n 7)
       (setq args (append args
              (make-list (- 7 n) nil))))
     (unless val
       (setq val ""))
     (setq args (nconc args (list val)))
     (apply #'org+-table-get args)))

(gv-define-simple-setter
 org+-table-get
 org+-table-setter)

(defun org+-table-add-header-hline (table)
  "Add hline below header row by modifying TABLE.
Return the modified TABLE."
  (setcdr table (cons 'hline (cdr table)))
  table)
```

With those definitions the code in the following Org file would work:

```
#+tblname: site-charac-matrix
|   | glaze | orn | color | thin |
|---+-------+-----+-------+------|
| A |     0 |   1 |     0 |    0 |
| B |     1 |   0 |     0 |    0 |
| C |     1 |   0 |     1 |    0 |
| D |     1 |   1 |     1 |    1 |
| E |     0 |   1 |     1 |    1 |

#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :var matrix=site-charac-matrix site="E" char='color :colnames no
(format "At site %s the pottery does%s have the %s characteristic.\n"
    site
    (if (eq (org+-table-get matrix site char) 1)
        ""
      " not")
    char)
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: At site D the pottery does have the color characteristic.

Also setting table cells is possible:
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :var matrix=site-charac-matrix site="E" char='color val=2 :colnames no
(setf (org+-table-get matrix site char) val)
(org+-table-add-header-hline matrix)
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
|   | glaze | orn | color | thin |
|---+-------+-----+-------+------|
| A |     0 |   1 |     0 |    0 |
| B |     1 |   0 |     0 |    0 |
| C |     1 |   0 |     1 |    0 |
| D |     1 |   1 |     1 |    1 |
| E |     0 |   1 |     2 |    1 |
```

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of different ways to write code that's similar but a bit different. So the question might be closed as being a bit opinion-based.

Anyway, here's one rewrite, which factors some of the stuff.  I don't claim it is in any particular way better than what you wrote.

```lisp
(setq site-matrix  '((A 0 1 0 0) (B 1 0 0 0) (C 1 0 1 0) (D 1 1 1 1) (E 0 1 1 1)))

(defun site-charac-4 (site charac)
  (let* ((ii  (1- site))
         (jj  (nth (cl-case charac
                     (glaze 1)
                     (orn   2)
                     (color 3)
                     (thin  4))
                   (nth ii site-matrix)))
         (dn  (if (= 1 jj) "" " not")))
    (and (member site '(1 2 3 4 5))
         (format "At site %d the pottery does%s have the %s characteristic." site dn charac))))

;; (site-charac-4 5 'color)
;; => "At site 5 the pottery does have the color characteristic."
```

Comment: What you and the others have offered is exactly what I, a beginner, need. (I'm teaching this stuff to a local YMCA STEM club, BTW.) So maybe examples shouldn't be condemned as "opinions?" That would be assigning motives and intent to honest suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

This is an [X-Y-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Just avoid the multi-branched conditionals if you actually do not need them.
I show you one way to do that with the code below.

The most important details of the code:

- If you use the `:colnames no` header argument  you get the characteristics in the first line of the matrix.
- You can get the column number of the given characteristic with the column names with `cl-position`.
- You can select the site with its site name via `assoc-string`.
- You can process multiple characteristics at once for one site with `cl-loop`.

```
#+tblname: site-charac-matrix
|   | glaze | orn | color | thin |
|---+-------+-----+-------+------|
| A |     0 |   1 |     0 |    0 |
| B |     1 |   0 |     0 |    0 |
| C |     1 |   0 |     1 |    0 |
| D |     1 |   1 |     1 |    1 |
| E |     0 |   1 |     1 |    1 |

#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :results none
(defun site-char (matrix site &rest characteristics)
  "Report whether SITE has CHARACTERISTICS in MATRIX.
MATRIX is a cons (COLSROW . DATA).
COLSROW is a a cons (\"\" . PROPS) where
the list PROPS contains the property names.
DATA contains the data rows.
Each data row is a cons (NAME . FLAGS).
NAME contains the name of the site as string or symbol.
FLAGS is a list of flags with the same length as PROPS.
SITE is one of the site names in MATRIX.
CHARACTERISTICS is a list with names from PROPS.
SITE's flags are those associated with SITE in DATA.
SITE can also be the site's row index."
  (when (numberp site) ;; unify treatment of sites
    (unless (and (> site 0)
         (<= site (length (car matrix))))
      (user-error "Index out of range"))
    (setq site (car (nth site matrix))))
  (let (col row)
    (setq row (assoc-string site matrix))
    (unless row
      (user-error "Site %s unknown." site))
    (cl-loop for char in characteristics
         if (setq col (cl-position char (car matrix) :test #'string-equal))
         collect (format "At site %s the pottery does%s have the %s characteristic.\n"
                 site
                 (if (eq (nth col row) 1)
                 ""
                   " not")
                 char)
         else
         do (user-error "Characteristic %s unknown" char))))
#+END_SRC

#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :var matrix=site-charac-matrix site="E" char='color :colnames no
(site-char matrix site char)
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
| At site E the pottery does have the color characteristic. |
```

Comment: Does it not seem counterintuitive that you have to say `:colnames no` to get the column names?

Comment: I don't think this is an "X-Y Problem" per se. Yes, I have a working solution, but I'm merely asking for a better way to do it from all the more experienced people out there.

Comment: @NickD Yes that is one of those rare features where I have to consult the Org manual every time I use it. I think that is almost "counterintuitive by definition".

Comment: But do you think that the manual accurately describes the behavior? I don't really understand what it says, but it feels like a bug to me. I guess I'll ask on the ML.

Comment: @NickD Yes the manual describes the right behavior. `:colnames` switches off the special treatment of column names and therefore you get them. That is just confusing. That's for sure!

Answer (score 1):

I might be missing the point of the question, but I think the main reason this looks messy is that the cond statement has 5 branches. A nested conditional on its own doesn't look that bad to me, so noticing that the only thing changing in the main cond branch is the argument to `nth`, I would rewrite the function as

```
(defun site-charac-4 (site charac)
  (if (and (< 0 site) (> 6 site))
      (format "At site %d the pottery %s have the %s characteristic." 
          site
          (if (= 1 (nth (charac-to-index charac)
                (nth (- site 1) site-matrix)))
              "does"
            "does not")
          charac)))
```